# How to get Exceptions log from console and write it to external file?

Tags: java, logging, groovy, exception, spock

I am trying to implement a Logger for my automation script which will log every information to a separate file, but i am not able to find a way to print the exceptions to that file. i have tried using `System.setErr(mOutputStream)` but by the time Exception is printed to console my test execution gets stopped and outputStrem gets closed automatically.
Is there any way so that i can fetch all the `Exception` from console to my in the sequence they appeared.

I only want to filter all the exceptions from console.

Comment: Use log4j jar ..

Comment: i have written my own logic to generate a file and write logs in that, is there any other way to get the Exceptions from console which are not handled in code and write it to file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using log4j (see [*link*](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)).

In your `log4j.properties` file you have to use `FileAppender`, for example:

```
log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=/your-path/your-file.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```

`FileAppender` appends log events to a file.